# sympy: how to print matrix product before evaluating it?

Tags: python, sympy

I have two matrices, say `a, b` and I want to print (in a readable way) both

1. `<a> @ <b>`, **without** actually performing the matrix multiplication
2. the actual result of the multiplication (as performed by sympy)

is there any way to do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the unevaluated symbolic product using `MatMul`:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html#sympy.matrices.expressions.MatMul

```
In [16]: from sympy import *                                                                                                                   

In [17]: A = Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])                                                                                                          

In [18]: B = Matrix([[5, 6], [7, 8]])                                                                                                          

In [19]: product = MatMul(A, B)                                                                                                                

In [20]: product                                                                                                                               
Out[20]: 
⎡1  2⎤ ⎡5  6⎤
⎢    ⎥⋅⎢    ⎥
⎣3  4⎦ ⎣7  8⎦

In [21]: product.doit()                                                                                                                        
Out[21]: 
⎡19  22⎤
⎢      ⎥
⎣43  50⎦

In [22]: Eq(product, product.doit())                                                                                                           
Out[22]: 
⎡1  2⎤ ⎡5  6⎤   ⎡19  22⎤
⎢    ⎥⋅⎢    ⎥ = ⎢      ⎥
⎣3  4⎦ ⎣7  8⎦   ⎣43  50⎦
```